# Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of null at HTMLDivElement.closeIframeContainer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, postmessage

I have a simple block which contains an iframe, I would like a user to be able to close the iframe using a button. But unfortunately I am getting the following error.

Here is what I have so far

JS

```
  document.querySelector(.video-close_btn).addEventListener('click', closeIframeContainer);
    var closeIframeContainer =function(){
        window.parent.postMessage("event=closeiframe", "*");
    };

    window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessageFromIframe, false);
    function receiveMessageFromIframe(msg) {
        if (event == "closeiframe") {
            document.getElementById('iframe-container').remove();
        }else{
           alert('hehehe');
        }
    }
```

Here is index.html with iframe

```
<div id="iframe-container">

            <iframe src="/videoexplainer/data.html" style="border:none"></iframe>
    </div>
```

Here is data.html

```
 <div id="video-close_btn" class="video-btn">
                    <img src="images/x.png" />
                </div>
```

unfortunately its not working, what do I need to do get what I want? any help or suggestions will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You need to assign `closeIframeContainer` before you use it as the argument to `addEventListener`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the real code? You never use `window` as a property name. The error message is complaining about `something.window`, where `something == null`.

Comment: And `closeIframeContainer` is a top-level function, it's not a property of `HTMLDivElement`.